# Combining two script in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have two script in javascript/jquery. How i will combine in one. On body load this function run

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function() {
       var tId = setInterval(function() {
         document.getElementById("link1").disabled=!navigator.onLine;
       },250);
                  </script>

    <script>   
       var status = navigator.onLine;
    if (status) {
    $("#link1").removeClass('diconnected').addClass('connected');
    $("#link1").data('disabled',true);
    } else {
    $("#link1").removeClass('connected').addClass('diconnected');
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stackoverflow is not an automatic-free-online-weird-code-merging tool

Comment: Have you started with the obvious and just removed the `</script> <script>` from between them?

Comment: @Pointy: yes i did that, but not confirm it will behave proper or not

Comment: It will; so long as the code isn't throwing an error, the semantics of two script blocks right next to each other is the same as one big block. In your first script, you're missing a `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var status = navigator.onLine;
if (status) {
$("#link1").removeClass('diconnected').addClass('connected');
$("#link1").data('disabled',true);
} else {
$("#link1").removeClass('connected').addClass('diconnected');
}window.onload=function() {
           var tId = setInterval(function() {
             document.getElementById("link1").disabled=!navigator.onLine;
           },250);
       }});
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Your first script is missing a closing bracket }

If you add in a } you can remove the closing and opening script tags.

Additionally, you may want the second bit of code within the window.onload function, which would mean you could put the closing bracket } after the 2nd scripts code